# How to open Google Drive File with Coinbase Wallet Backup

Tags: wallet, coinbase.com

How do I open and access the Coinbase Wallet backup file in Google Drive? I've been locked out Coinbase Wallet but I have that Google Drive back up file. The problem is that when I open it, it's completely blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't know coibbase offered non costodial wallets. What format is it in? Do you see 12 or 24 random words? Do you see a string of hex characters? I would say electrum wallet is a great open source wallets that allows you to import private keys from many different places.

Comment: I should have said don't post the contents of whatever backup you have in case it wasn't obvious